# Transcendental equation $\cos (z)+\sin (z)=2$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

> Solve $\cos(z)+\sin(z)=2$

My work:
\begin{alignat}{2}
\cos(z)+\sin(z)=2 & \implies e^{iz}&&+e^{-iz}+e^{-iz}-e^{iz}=4\\
&\implies e^{-iz}&&=2 \\
&\implies e^{-iz}&&=e^{\ln(2)+2\pi ni} \\
&\implies-iz&&=\ln(2)+2\pi ni \\
&\implies z&&=i\ln(2)-2 \pi n \\
\end{alignat}
but apparently the answer is $z=\frac{\pi}{4}+2n\pi \pm i\ln(\sqrt{2}+1)$.

Where have I made a mistake and why?

Comment: It looks like you tried to clear the denominator by multiplying by $2$ but the expression for the sine function has an $i$ in the denominator.

Comment: $2\sin z=-ie^{iz}+ie^{-iz}$, not what you have in the first line.

Comment: One way to solve this is to multiply by $\sqrt{2}/2$, which is equal to $\cos(\pi/4)$ and $\sin(\pi/4)$. Then a trig identity tells you $\sin(z+\pi/4)=\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$\cos{(z)}=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$
$$\sin{(z)}=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$

Comment: I've used those expressions though. $\frac{1}{i}$ is -1, right?

Comment: NO! $\frac1i=\frac{i}{i^2}=-i$. If $\frac1i=-1$, then $i=-1$ which is not true.